How to implement multiple option based output using "Microsoft Rules Engine"?
I am using "Microsoft Rules Engine" (https://microsoft.github.io/RulesEngine/).
I want to know how to implement multiple option based output for each rule to implement a questionnaire based points assignment.
eg:
Question might be:

"When did you sign up?"

Options and points will be:

a) < 1 year = 1 point
b) 2 - 4 years = 2 points
c) > 5 years = 3 points
d) not signed up = 0 points

So, the rule should be able to output success event with the respective points.
There will be up to 10 questions, so there will be 10 rules in the workflow.
Any ideas how to implement this?

Not sure how you define the input object. I think one of the option is add a new property to hold points in your input object:
ex: input1.Points
It's allowed to access the points info while analysing the rules results.

@PrasadRamireddy
The input comes from 3rd party sources and I cannot define the points there.

As I know, RulesEngine defines only two values for a rule : Success (true) or Failure (false).
Your expressions should always return a boolean. But to evaluate the rule you can calculate some information based on the inputs using local or global params :
"GlobalParams":[
{
  "Name":"SignUpPoints",
  "Expression":"input.SignUpSince==0 ? 0 : (input.SignUpSince<2 ? 1 : (input.SignUpSince<4 ? 2 : 3)) "
}

You can then use SignUpPoints to evaluate your rules. You can also use the Post Rules Actions to output the values using the same expression (OutputExpression in Actions definition).
But the first question to ask is : what should evaluate your workflow ? What are the rules that you try to check ?

Why is GlobalParam used?
